# How to write a file and eliminate lines?

Tags: python, arrays, file

I want to read from a file various lines like this for example:

```
hello   I live in London.
hello   I study.
```

And then based on what is the first word I want to remove the line from the file.

Can I put which sentence in a array?

Comment: How far did you get on your own, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Also, no arrays in python. Be more descriptive with the question.

Comment: I can remove the line if the sentence only has the word in the beginning I'm looking for. If it has more words in front nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in the entire contents of the file into memory (into a list), choose which lines you wish to keep, and write those a new file (you can replace the old one if you wish).

For example:

```
old_lines = open("input.txt",'r').readlines() 
new_lines = []

for line in old_lines:
     words = line.split()
     if words[0] == 'hello': # if the first word is "hello", keep it.
         new_lines.append(line)

f = open("output.txt",'w')
for line in new_lines:
    f.write(line)
```

Comment: By the way, can I replace one of the words of the phrase for the one in the beginning?

Comment: Yes. You can use the `split` method as I have used, to split a line up by whitespace, into a list. I.e. `"Hello this is a".split()` returns `["Hello","this","is","a"]`. Then you can access any of the list members, change them to a different word, and then turn the list back into a sentence by using `'(space)'.join(list_var)`

Comment: I want to replace one word of the sentence for the hello word that was in the beginning. My problem is how do I found the word in the sentence?

Comment: What do you mean by list_var ?